# Can someone explain this entry in debug.log file?

Tags: magento-2.1, log, debug

I found this in `debug.log` file on my **Magento ver. 2.1.8** store but don't really understand what it is saying. Can someone explain?

```
http://lb1.i:80/)"],"tagsPattern":"((^|,)catalog_product_3666(,|$))|((^|,)catalog_category_product_55(,|$))|((^|,)catalog_category_product_65(,|$))|((^|,)catalog_category_product_127(,|$))|((^|,)catalog_product_3668(,|$))"},"is_exception":false} []
```

Comment: Do you have varnish on the server?

Comment: Yes I use Varnish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern in your debug.log is trigger on product save.

In **InvalidateVarnishObserver (module-cache-invalidate):**

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    if ($this->config->getType() == \Magento\PageCache\Model\Config::VARNISH && $this->config->isEnabled()) {
        $object = $observer->getEvent()->getObject();
        if ($object instanceof \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface) {
            $tags = [];
            $pattern = "((^|,)%s(,|$))";
            foreach ($object->getIdentities() as $tag) {
                $tags[] = sprintf($pattern, preg_replace("~_\\d+$~", '', $tag));
                $tags[] = sprintf($pattern, $tag);
            }
            $this->purgeCache->sendPurgeRequest(implode('|', array_unique($tags)));
        }
    }
}
```

Will trigger a purge request for any object with X-Magento-Tag matching ((^|,)catalog_product(,|$))|((^|,)catalog_product_(,|$)).

You can read more [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4688).

Comment: Yhyyy, so it's saying that if product was changed or "saved", purge varnish cache for this product? So this entry in the debug.log file is only informative? Thank you for your interest, you are helpful!